# Firebase, Security Rules, how to check a item of array String size

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

the way of getting and verifying array list size in Firestore is below

```
request.resource.data.arraylist.size() < 10
```

but I want to know the "request.resource.data.arraylist[last_index].length" not the "list size"

how do I figure out this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Bytes`, `List`, `Map`, `Set`, and `String` variable types in the [`rules` namespace](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules) all share the `size()` method which is used in place of `length`.

So, using that, you would assert the last element has a size of less than 10 using:

```js
request.resource.data.arraylist[request.resource.data.arraylist.size()-1].size() < 10
```

Because that looks messy (especially amongst other conditions), you could rewrite it as a [custom function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) like so:

```js
function doesLastElementOfListHaveSizeLessThan(num, list) {
  return list[list.size()-1].size() < num;
}

doesLastElementOfListHaveSizeLessThan(10, request.resource.data.arraylist);
```

**Notes:**

- You can name the function whatever you want, I just used a sentence for clarity and it makes rereading your rules later easier.
- While this rule asserts the length of the last index, other indexes could have been modified to be longer than your threshold in the same write.
- For performance reasons, security rules do not support iteration, you must hard code in each check for an index manually. If you need to check a range of indexes, you should implement a custom function that checks a small range of indexes that takes a starting offset. If you implement such a function, make sure that it short-circuits to `true`/`false` as soon as possible and doesn't throw errors such as the index being out of bounds.

Comment: Great explanation but I want to ensure this. Although I expressed this as the last index in the question,  it could be also a real-time input value from the client to the server right? I mean is that correct "last index == incoming data"?

Comment: If you were using `arrayUnion` or `arrayRemove`, generally the last element is the one modified. But as I stated in the notes at the end, any entry in the array could have been modified. If you need to place the restriction on all elements, see [my answer on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67850444/3068190) where I implemented the function I was referring to in this one's notes.

Comment: thanks I use arrayUnion() method on my client code, I am still testing this code dont know why not working haha actually I was about to ask if arrayUnion is not working in this case