# Is firestore rules list index 0-based or 1-based?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Bcz it's not mentioned here [firestore rules/List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List), so I want know.

Comment: I will forewarn that securing arrays of objects can [be a real pain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67850444/3068190), so carefully consider what you are using them for and whether you should use documents in a collection instead.

Comment: No I just use array to store strings, btw thanks for your warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 0 based like in most languages. I could not find a place in the doc where it is explicitly said but my rules work and they us the 0 based assumption.

Comment: yeah, I also had to figure it out from the rules, hope they'd soon mention that

Comment: They explain it a [googleblog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), which is a bit odd, but my understanding is that this is likely something they intended to be implicit. However, after later realizing that this wasn't easily assumed, and wanting to have something a little easier to find than a specific paragraph in documentation (or possibly because it was difficult to decide a specific document to put this in), they chose to publish this as a Firebase Blog Entry.