# limiting array size in security rules cloud firestore using request.resorce.data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have the two following security rules the later checks if the document premiumUitill value in DB is bigger that current time meaning the premium is valid.

the issue here is with the first rule I want to disable array size so it won't pass 50 of length and I am pushing using `arrayUninon(data)` should I check for the size of `resource.data`rather than `request.resorce.data` ? in my testing `request.resource.data.arr.size()` < 50 works but it doesn't make sense to check the incoming data since the incoming has the payload only is something with the `arrayUnion()` that makes it work ?

```js
await updateDoc(docRef, {
      arr: arrayUnion(payload),
    }).catch((error) => {
      errorHandeling(error, 'An error has happened', reduxDispatch, SetSnackBarMsg);
    });
```

```js
&& request.resource.data.arr.size() < 50
&& resource.data.premiumUntill > request.time
```

Comment: I have provided an answer below. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Firestore security rules, resource refers to the existing document in the database, and request.resource refers to the document as it exists in the request (during a write, i.e. a set or update).

From the documentation on [data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation):

> The resource variable refers to the requested document, and resource.data is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document. For more information on the resource variable, see the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource).
>
> When writing data, you may want to compare incoming data to existing data. In this case, if your ruleset allows the pending write, the request.resource variable contains the future state of the document. For update operations that only modify a subset of the document fields, the request.resource variable will contain the pending document state after the operation. You can check the field values in request.resource to prevent unwanted or inconsistent data updates:
>
> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
>     // the name is not changed
>     match /cities/{city} {
>       allow update: if request.resource.data.population > 0
>                     && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Additionally you may watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&t=628s)  and also may have a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848352/firestore-security-rules-how-to-limit-a-size-of-array-of-map-field-content)

Comment: Does this answer your question?